# Thymeleaf spring boot jpa can't get data fom the dabase, no error detected

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a project using Spring Boot and I'm trying to integrate Thymeleaf to get information from the database. It's the first time I use Thymeleaf.

Here my entity class:

```
package com.org.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the countries database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
//@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c")

public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COUNTRY_ID")
    private String countryId;

    @Column(name="COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String countryName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Region

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="REGION_ID")
    private Region region;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Location
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
    private List<Location> locations;

    public Country() {
    }

    public String getCountryId() {
        return this.countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return this.countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public Region getRegion() {
        return this.region;
    }

    public void setRegion(Region region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return this.locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }

    public Location addLocation(Location location) {
        getLocations().add(location);
        location.setCountry(this);

        return location;
    }

    public Location removeLocation(Location location) {
        getLocations().remove(location);
        location.setCountry(null);

        return location;
    }

}
```

here is my controller:

```
package com.org.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.org.model.Country;
import com.org.repository.CountryRepository;

    @Controller    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/api", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) // This means that this class is a Controller

public class CountryController {
        @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
        // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;



        @RequestMapping(value="/country", method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public String list(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("Country", countryRepository.findAll());


            // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
            return "countries";
        }


    //  @RequestMapping(path="/country/{countryId}")
    //    public @ResponseBody Country getCountry(@PathVariable String countryId) {
    //        return countryRepository.findOne(countryId);
    //    }
    }
```

I create a HTML file to display the data in a table:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
    <head lang="en">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->

    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(countries)}">

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Country Id</th>
                    <th>Country Name</th>
                    <th>Region Id</th>
                    <th>Location</th>

                </tr>
                <tr th:ForEach="Country : ${countries}">
                    <td th:text="${Country.countryId}">id country</td>
                    <td th:text="${Country.countryName}">Country Name</td>
                    <td th:text="${Country.region}">Region Id</td>
                    <td th:text="${Country.locations}">Location</td>

                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I added the Thymleaf dependency to the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxxx.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>webService</name>
    <description>first project for university</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
  <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I got no error but white screen no error in the console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that thymeleaf don't accept ForEach, i change it to each and he accept it.

Comment: If this solved the problem I suggest you mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @NasSim Isn't that the same as what I said?

Answer (score 0):

You added the modelAttribute with name "Country", but in Thymeleaf you try to call "countries" fix that by setting the modelAttribute to:

```
model.addAttribute("countries", countryRepository.findAll());
```

**EDIT:**

Also change your thymeleaf to this.

```
<tr th:each="Country : ${countries}">
```

Check [this list](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes) to see what names you can use. (if it doesn't automatically scroll to the chapter, it's *5.2 Setting value to specific attributes*.

Comment: i did that and now i got this error: 
'There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "country.countryId" (countries:22)'
'org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'countryId' cannot be found on null'

Comment: I don't know what you got going on with having an entity with `@Id String`, so I think you might also have a Hibernate issue. Try creating a couple of `Countries` in your controller method and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but I had kind of similar issue, are you sure you are accessing your database and not one created at runtime using your Entity.

Check that countryRepository.findAll() is returning records.

Comment: yes i fact the controller working fine and i have acess to the data, but the probem occur only when i use thymeleaf to display the data in html file.